# SystemUtil.Run in UFT gives me "invalid procedure call or argument", Why?

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, invalid-argument

I'm using `SystemUtil.Run (pathName)` in UFT, VBScript. But it gives me

> invalid procedure call or argument.

I'm sure about pathName, I'm sure about the command, I'm sure about everything. What do you think might be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the examples [here](http://www.automationrepository.com/2011/12/understanding-systemutil-run-syntax-with-examples/), you'll see that the approved call is

```
SystemUtil.Run pathName
```

(passing pathName per reference) instead of

```
SystemUtil.Run (pathName)
```

(passing a const copy).

Eric Lippert's [essay](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) should help you to understand the use of () in VBScript.

**Evidence:**

As I don't use UFT, I can only use .NET to demonstrate that the ()/parameter passing mode matters:

```
>> Set m_oSB = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
>> aData = Split("a b c")
>> m_oSB.AppendFormat_4 "{0}-{1}-{2}", (aData)
>> WScript.Echo m_oSB.ToString()
>>
a-b-c
>> m_oSB.AppendFormat_4 "{0}-{1}-{2}", aData
>>
Error Number:       5
Error Description:  Invalid procedure call or argument
>>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what console (if any at all) are you using there?

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into the same issue. I had to write the full path name for the error to go away.

example: SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "www.google.com"

I hope this helps you.