# "Invalid procedure call" error when passing a variable as argument vs. passing the return value of another function

Tags: .net, vbscript

I get an error:

> invalid procedure call or argument: 'AddRange'

when passing a variable to [ArrayList.AddRange()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zhfwys3c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but the code works fine when I pass the return value of a function instead, i.e.

My list:

```
Dim Foo
Set Foo = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

Adding a new list returned by `GetList()` works fine:

```
Call Foo.AddRange(GetList()) ' works fine

Function GetList()
  Set GetList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
End Function
```

but passing a new list with a variable (`x`) raises an error:

```
Dim x
Set x = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Call Foo.AddRange(x)  ' error: invalid procedure call or argument: 'AddRange'
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to pass the array list by value. This works:

```
Call Foo.AddRange((x))
```

The inner set of parentheses causes the argument to be passed `ByVal` instead of `ByRef`.

Comment: That works, but why? I was thinking that during execution a method `ArrayList.AddRange(object)` was searched for and not found, since there is only a `ArrayList.AddRange(ICollection)`, but given your answer, this doesn't seem to be the right.

Comment: I suspect that `AddRange` doesn't accept object references, and that the return value of the function is implicitly passed by value instead of by reference, but I don't know where (or if) this is documented.

Comment: Sorry, no doc nor theory, but another instance of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31455471/603855